# Traffic 2 sample netlogo road patches

Tags: netlogo

So i created some vans on traffic 2 sample and i want my vans to be on top of the road and cars on the bottom.
if i use `set ycor -2` or `set ycor 2`instead of `move-to one-of free road-patches` my interface is like that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd5Kq.png) (screenshot) but if i`m using the normal code  it is randomly like that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d18N6.png)(screenshot).

Can anyone help me with this ? I need my vans to be on the upper patch and my cars on the bottom patch of the road but not after the "bycicle street line" like in the first picture

Comment: offhand, It looks like you want `set ycor -1` and `set ycor 1` instead of -2 and 2?

Comment: It`s working with -1 and 1.Thanks!

Comment: Cool. I added this as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to `set ycor -1` and `set ycor 1`, because 2 and -2 are too far.